# Disabling default AlarmClock alarm

Tags: android, clock, alarm

I've set an alarm in the default AlarmClock app. How to disable that previously set alarm? I didn't use AlarmManager for this.

```
    Intent alarm = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(11,13));
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(14,16));
        if((message.substring(17,19).equalsIgnoreCase("AM") || message.substring(17,19).equalsIgnoreCase("PM")))
        {
            if(message.substring(17,19).equalsIgnoreCase("AM"))
            {
                alarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
            }
            else
                alarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour+12);

            alarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes);
            alarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, name+": "+message.substring(20));

        }
        startActivity(alarm);
```

In the string message, I'm taking the hour, minutes and AM/PM from the user.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) How did you set the alarm? Please provide some code, it's hard to help without.

Comment: @thegrinner: I know I can do that using AlarmManager but I want to use AlarmClock. I've edited my question by inserting the code. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the answer for this question until now but I think some other guys will be need...
Please try : 
`Intent itentChangeAlarm = new Intent("android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED");
    alarmChanged.putExtra("alarmSet", enabled);
    context.sendBroadcast(itentChangeAlarm);`